# Chatbot IBM WATSON Get facebook name in MSN

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I had been trying to get the names automaticaly, but it didnt seems to work, so I'm asking the ussers for their names and putting it as a variable. Is there a way to make the chatbot get the name when the conversation starts?[image]

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the Watson Assistant documentation, sys-person has been deprecated as of 2020. [See this posting.](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-system-entities) The suggestion as detailed in the Blog "[Detecting Names And Locations With Watson Assistant"](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/detecting-names-and-locations-with-watson-assistant-e3e1fa2a8427)is to use Contextual Entities.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now, there is no way to get the defaut name in facebook MSN unless the user gives his name. Sad jaja